# How to solve " Variable..... not found in scope...."?

Tags: openmodelica

I've tried to build a very simple model in order to learn using CombiTable in Open Modelica. I want to output the value of the table (  in particular y[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctk9z.jpg) ).Can you help me please? I show you pictures with errors. Thank you very much. I'm using last version 1.12.0-64bit.[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In line 3 you are setting columns=2:size(table,2). But variable table is nowhere defined in your script. You're probably thinking of table as an array, if that's the case, you have to define it.

If it's not the case and you're just testing modelica you can use a constant columns =2:N with N the number of columns in your table on the file.